# Dynamic Unrolling of Simple Neural Nets using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to replicate a neural net to compute the energy of molecules (image given below). The Energy is the sum of bonded/non-bonded interactions and angle/dihedral strains. I have 4 separate neural networks that find out the energy due to each of these, and the total energy is the sum of energies due to each interaction, there may be 100s of these. In my data-set, I only know the total energy.

If my total energy is computed **using multiple (an unknown number, decided by the molecule) forward-pos on different neural networks, how do I get keras to backpropagate through the dynamically constructued sum**. A non-keras Tensorflow method would work too. (I would have just summed together the outputs of the neural nets if I knew before hand how many bonds would there be, the issue is having to unfold copies of the neural net at runtime).

This is just an example image given in the paper:
[image: Neural Network architecture]

In summary, the question is: "How do I implement dynamic unrolling and feed it to a sum in Keras?".

Comment: What have you tried? As your question currently stands, there is not much to answer.

Comment: I have nothing now, I know that RNNs unroll the neural net in real time, but here I need to unroll regular Dense nets in real time. I just need syntax, I know how I would implement using numpy per say.

Comment: Basically, my idea is that once I forward-POS all times and generate the final result, the backprop would go evenly to all the original nets, the was any sum function back-propagates. But I want to do that cleanly instead of coding up a lot of things, also the paper says they managed using Keras. Any syntax tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras layers can be given a shape of `(None, actual-shape...)` if one of the dimensions is not known. Then we can use a TensorFlow layer to sum over the axis indexed 0 using `tf.reduce_sum(layer, axis=0)`. So dynamic layer sizes are not hard to achieve in Keras.

However if the input shapes pose more of a constraint, we can pass in the full matrix with dummy 0 values appended, and a mask matrix, then we can use `tf.multiply` to reject the dummy values, the backpropagation will automatically work of course.